# Can not find part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I had pdf file and when i click on the button `export pdf` it gives me this error.
this error is appeared just when i deployed the application on `IIS 7`, things are good when i work whith `IIS Express` ( i can export the pdf file, open it and saved it on my pc).

This is the code:

```
DataTable dtbl = MakeDataTable();
ExportDataTableToPdf(dtbl, Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/PdfPaiement/PaiementPdf.pdf"), "");

// Ouvrir fichier Pdf 

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= 
PaiementPdf.pdf"); // Fournir le nom du fichier de paiement   
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"~/Downloads/PdfPaiement/PaiementPdf.pdf")); // acceder au fichier pdf

Response.End();    // terminer le response

Response.Flush();  // Initialiser le process
```

Comment: This is most likely a permission error. Check to see if your App Pool user from IIS has permissions to write to the folder you are specifying.

Comment: I think it's OK for people to post problems when changing application servers on Stack Overflow. IMO, the 2 down-votes and the close-vote aren't fair. The previous comment and the answer will probably solve the problem. One important note though: this question shouldn't have been tagged as an iText question. You have a PDF on disk, and you want to transmit it. In no way is this involves iText. If you argue: "but I created the PDF with iText", then why did you have to save the PDF on file? Why didn't you just create it in memory and transmit a `byte[]` from a `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a while ago and I had to give permissions to the `INTERNET GUEST ACCOUNT` under folder `Properties >> Security`.